# How to skip tasks when triggering a dag programmatically

Tags: airflow

Is there a way to trigger a dag  programmatically (say via API) but skip the first few tasks in the dag ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to trigger a dag programmatically..?

I'm aware of 3 ways

**1. Via an Airflow DAG itself**

Use [`TriggerDagRunOperator`](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/trigger-dag-operator/)

**2. Via [Airflow's `REST` API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/rest-api-ref.html#post--api-experimental-dags--DAG_ID--dag_runs)**

> `POST /api/experimental/dags/<DAG_ID>/dag_runs`
>
> Creates a dag_run for a given dag id.

**3. Airflow's `CLI`**

Use [`trigger_dag` command](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/cli-ref#trigger_dag)

---

> ..but skip the first few tasks in the dag?

Irrespective of whether DAG was triggered programmatically, manually via Airflow's CLI or UI, or by scheduler (normal schedule / `cron` time), the methods of *skipping* tasks are the same

**1. [`AirflowSkipException`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/exceptions/index.html#airflow.exceptions.AirflowSkipException)** (when you are using `PythonOperator` or any custom operator)

**2. [`BranchPythonOperator`](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-branch-operator/) or [`ShortCircuitOperator`](https://medium.com/@loraxman/how-and-why-of-airflow-shortciruitoperator-85dcbeddb1ba)** (these are dedicated operators for building conditional workflows)

Reference: [Schedule airflow job bi-weekly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63571789/3679900)

- Please understand that you CAN'T skip a `task` in a `DagRun` just like that: to skip tasks programmatically, the logic of skipping has to be baked into the tasks / workflow itself (at the time of building / defining the dag)
- But of course if you want to do it manually, it can be done via Airflow's UI itself (when a DAG is running) as told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59429726/3679900)

Comment: Thanks. So we found that when we trigger a task via API, we can pass a JSON which can be read in the context. then we can use this to raise the AirflowSkipException